# Jenkins pipeline groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

Tags: exception, jenkins, groovy, properties, jenkins-pipeline

I have simple groovy script that I'm using with Jenkins pipeline and fails on the **git merge** operation with kind of strange exception:

The script:

```
node("master") {
ws(env.BUILD_NUMBER.toString()) { // workspace
    withCredentials([
        [$class: 'UsernamePasswordBinding', credentialsId: 'bitbucket', variable: 'BITBUCKET_AUTH'],
        [$class: 'UsernamePasswordBinding', credentialsId: 'bitbucket-https', variable: 'BITBUCKET_HTTPS_AUTH'],]) {

        def applicationName = env.CUSTOMER_NAME
        def packageName = "no.bstcm.loyaltyapp.${env.REPO_NAME}"
        def googleServicesJsonContents = env.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON
        def bitbucketRepoName = "android_loyalty_app_${env.REPO_NAME}"
        def bitbucketRepoApiUrl = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/boost-development/${bitbucketRepoName}"
        def starterBranch = "shopping_mall"
        def projectPath = "jenkins-project"

        stage('Create repository on bitbucket') {
            sh "curl POST -v -u $BITBUCKET_AUTH $bitbucketRepoApiUrl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"is_private\": true, \"project\": {\"key\": \"LOY\"}}'"
        }

        stage('Create local repository') {
            dir(projectPath) {
                sh "git init"
                sh "touch README.md"
                sh "git add README.md"
                sh "git commit --message='Initial commit'"
            }
        }

        stage('Merge starter') {
            dir(projectPath) {
                sh "git init"
                sh "git remote add starter https://$BITBUCKET_HTTPS_AUTH@bitbucket.org/boost-development/app_designer_starter_android.git"
                sh "git fetch starter"
                sh "git checkout master" <--- FAILS HERE
                sh "git remote add origin https://$BITBUCKET_HTTPS_AUTH@bitbucket.org/boost-development/$bitbucketRepoName.git"
                sh "git push -u origin master"
                sh "git remote remove starter"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the exception I receive (and the pipeline broke):

```
[Pipeline] sh
[jenkins-project] Running shell script
+ git fetch starter
From https://bitbucket.org/***/***
 * [new branch]      master     -> starter/master
[Pipeline] sh
[jenkins-project] Running shell script
+ git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from starter.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // ws
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: git for 
class: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAd
apter.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:243)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onGetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:308)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:28)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:36)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
```

Do you guys have any idea what could cause this problem? I have no idea and google doesn't help much here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

trouble in this kind of groovy string:

```
sh ".... $bitbucketRepoName.git ...."
```

in this case groovy it tries to access property `git` of variable `bitbucketRepoName`

just change it this:

```
sh ".... ${bitbucketRepoName}.git ...."
```

Comment: Oh god thank you so much. You have no idea how much time I wasted by not noticing this syntax error and looking for jenkins related issues.