# Jenkins ${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=50, escapeHtml=false} not woking

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using the below code to override the BUILD_LOG functionality but i am not getting the complete console log.

Code :

```
  emailext body: '''$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - FAILURE:
Check console output at $BUILD_URL to view the results. ${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=50, escapeHtml=false}''', replyTo: 'noreply@bwpm.dumpmail', subject: '$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - FAILURE!', to: 'santhuhappy24@gmail.com'
```

Jenkins version i am using : Jenkins 2.79

Regards,

Santhohs

Comment: *I am using the below code to override the BUILD_LOG functionality but i am not getting the complete console log.* Is it because you're limiting yourself with `maxLines`?? `${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=50, escapeHtml=false}`

Comment: i have increased maxLines to 9999 but still i m not getting the full console logs..any other changes i need to make ?

Answer (score 0):

You are limiting the Build log to give only the last 50 lines. So instead of that please use a large number so that it will give you total log of the console.

```
${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=999999, escapeHtml=false}
```

I haven't seen getting full log using `$BUILD_LOG` it only give 250 lines which is default. I have tested using that number. Hope this helps for you too.

Comment: I tried with this code but still no luck ..${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=999999, escapeHtml=false}

Comment: Hi Madhava, Please find the below code what i am using.<table>
  <tr><th>Project Name:</th><td>$JOB_NAME</td></tr>
  <tr><th>Build Number:</th><td>$BUILD_NUMBER</td></tr>
  <tr><th>Build URL:</th><td>$BUILD_URL</td></tr>
  <tr><th>Jenkins Console Output:</th><td>$${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=999999, escapeHtml=false}</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>''', 
     replyTo: 'noreply@bwpm.dumpmail',
     subject: 'Jenkins Job  - FAILURE!',
     to: 'Santhosha.Shankaramurthy@sanofi.com'
   throw err

Comment: You are using `$${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=999999, escapeHtml=false}` Please remove that extra `$`. Now it will work.

Comment: Hi Madhav, I have added correct code but still i can get the output only partially...not complete error output..is there any thing i need to make changes ?

Comment: moreover i am unable to capture any error logs from Jenkins console to display it email notification

Comment: Hi Madhav,Line count is 71

Comment: Below is sample errror...groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: err for class: WorkflowScript
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:34)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
 at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:112)

Comment: These errors are because of the spacing in between the commands. So please add a space `${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=999999, escapeHtml=false}` after and before and see it worked or not. or else as your error says `WorkflowScript` look at it once.

Comment: Hope this helps for you too. [jenkins-pipeline-groovy-lang-missingpropertyexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44237260/jenkins-pipeline-groovy-lang-missingpropertyexception)

Comment: I tried both the steps you have mentioned above but the problem here it is unalbe to capture the error part in email apart from that it is working fine as expected. Ex: there are 50 lines in the code, till 25th line it will execute fine but after 26th line exception will start so that exception it is unable capture in the email body...Pls do the needfull.It is eating my head from last one week...thanks,Santhosh